# Extending Error when using Closure Compiler

Tags: javascript, inheritance, error-handling, google-closure-compiler

I'm using the Closure Compiler and trying to do subclassing of the Error 'class'. I have a meta-function that tries to do that. It looks like this:

```
/**
 * @param {string} name
 * @param {(function(new:Error)?)=} parent
 * @param {(Function?)=} constructor
 * @return {function(new:Error)}
 * @usage
 *      var MyError = subclassError('MyError', null, function (x, y) {
 *          this.message = prop1 + " " + prop2;
 *      });
 *      throw new MyError(new Error(), 1, 2);
**/
function subclassError (name, parent, constructor) {
    // allow subclassing of other errors
    if (!parent) parent = Error;
    // allow no constructor to be provided
    if (!constructor) {
        /** @this {Error} */
        constructor = function (msg) { if (msg) this.message = msg; };
    }
    /** 
     * @constructor
     * @extends {Error}
     * @param {Error} error
     * @param {...*} var_args
    **/
    var func = function (error, var_args) {
        // this check is just a guard against further errors
        // note that we don't use something like getOwnPropertyNames
        // as this won't work in older IE
        var propsToCopy = ['fileName', 'lineNumber', 'columnNumber', 
           'stack', 'description', 'number', 'message'];
        for (var i = 0; i < propsToCopy.length; i++) {
            this[propsToCopy[i]] = error[propsToCopy[i]];
        }
        this.name = name;
        constructor.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    };
    func.prototype = Object.create(parent.prototype);
    func.prototype.constructor = func;
    func.name = constructor.name;
    return func;
}
```

Basically, the above function creates a subclass of Error, which when called requires passing in a native `Error` object. From this object it fills in stuff like line number, stack trace, etc. But it also allows you to pass in other parameters.

Here's a sample of using it:

```
/**
 * @constructor
 * @extends {Error}
 * @param {Error} err
 * @param {number} bar
 * @param {number} baz
**/
var FooError = subclassError('FooError', null, function (bar, baz) {
    this.message = "invalid bar: '" + bar + "', (using '" + baz + "')";
});

/**
 * Frobs the noid.
 * @param {number} x
 * @param {number} y
 * @throws FooError
**/
function frob (x, y) {
    if (x < 0) throw new FooError(new Error(), x, y);
}
```

When I compile this with Closure like so:

```
java -jar compiler.jar
    --compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS --warning_level VERBOSE
    --language_in ECMASCRIPT5 --language_out ECMASCRIPT3
    --js_output_file=frob.min.js frob.js
```

I get the following warnings:

```
frob.js:39: WARNING - inconsistent return type
found   : function (new:func, (Error|null), ...*): undefined
required: function (new:Error): ?
    return func;
           ^

frob.js:60: WARNING - Function FooError: called with 3
        argument(s). Function requires at least 0 argument(s) and no more
        than 0 argument(s).
    if (x < 0) throw new FooError(new Error(), x, y);
```

One of the tricky things here is that although I know (from the code) that the `func` object descends from `Error`, since either a descendant of `Error` was passed in *or* we use `Error` as the parent, Closure thinks that it's an instance of `func` and that this not an instance of `Error`. I tried adding an `@extends {Error}` in the above to rectify the problem, but Closure still thinks `!(func instanceof Error)`. This is the first warning.

In the second warning, the problem is that it doesn't recognize that `FooError` takes three arguments. I tried to add three parameters to `FooError`, but since Closure doesn't see the parameter list, it can't find that out.

Is there a way to get rid of these warnings by telling Closure more information? Or is there a way to extend `Error` in Closure in a simpler way that allows us to get the line number, stack, etc.?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you didn't use the standard prototype inheritance from the `Error` object? `function FooError() {}; FooError.prototype = new Error();`

Comment: Never mind - I forgot how much of a pain the Error object was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are calling a method that returns a constructor, we have to be a little tricky in order to get full type checking in the compiler.

First, change the `subclassError` method to return the unknown type so that we can define the type signature independently:

```
/**
 * @param {string} name
 * @param {(function(new:Error)?)=} parent
 * @param {(Function?)=} constructor
 * @return {?}
 **/
function subclassError (name, parent, constructor) {}
```

Next, we add a stub definition for `FooError` so that the compiler can understand type information. Then we actually assign the result of the `subclassError` method.

```
/**
 * @constructor
 * @extends {Error}
 * @param {Error} err
 * @param {number} bar
 * @param {number} baz
 **/
var FooError = function(err, bar, baz) {};

FooError = subclassError('FooError', null, function (bar, baz) {
  this.message = "invalid bar: '" + bar + "', (using '" + baz + "')";
});
```

Now we get correct type checking from the compiler

```
// The compiler will warn that FooError is called with
// the wrong number of arguments
new FooError(new Error());
```

[See a Full Example](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home#code%3D%252F%252F%2520%253D%253DClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540compilation_level%2520ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540output_file_name%2520default.js%250A%252F%252F%2520%253D%253D%252FClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%250A%252F**%250A%2520*%2520%2540param%2520%257Bstring%257D%2520name%250A%2520*%2520%2540param%2520%257B%28function%28new%253AError%29%253F%29%253D%257D%2520parent%250A%2520*%2520%2540param%2520%257B%28Function%253F%29%253D%257D%2520constructor%250A%2520*%2520%2540return%2520%257B%253F%257D%250A%2520**%252F%250Afunction%2520subclassError%2520%28name%252C%2520parent%252C%2520constructor%29%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%252F%252F%2520allow%2520subclassing%2520of%2520other%2520errors%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520if%2520%28!parent%29%2520parent%2520%253D%2520Error%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%252F%252F%2520allow%2520no%2520constructor%2520to%2520be%2520provided%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520if%2520%28!constructor%29%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%252F**%2520%2540this%2520%257BError%257D%2520*%252F%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520constructor%2520%253D%2520function%2520%28msg%29%2520%257B%2520if%2520%28msg%29%2520this.message%2520%253D%2520msg%253B%2520%257D%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%252F**%2520%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520*%2520%2540constructor%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520*%2520%2540extends%2520%257BError%257D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520*%2520%2540param%2520%257BError%257D%2520error%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520*%2520%2540param%2520%257B...*%257D%2520var_args%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520**%252F%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520func%2520%253D%2520function%2520%28error%252C%2520var_args%29%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%252F%252F%2520this%2520check%2520is%2520just%2520a%2520guard%2520against%2520further%2520errors%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%252F%252F%2520note%2520that%2520we%2520don't%2520use%2520something%2520like%2520getOwnPropertyNames%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%252F%252F%2520as%2520this%2520won't%2520work%2520in%2520older%2520IE%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520propsToCopy%2520%253D%2520%255B'fileName'%252C%2520'lineNumber'%252C%2520'columnNumber'%252C%2520%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520'stack'%252C%2520'description'%252C%2520'number'%252C%2520'message'%255D%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520for%2520%28var%2520i%2520%253D%25200%253B%2520i%2520%253C%2520propsToCopy.length%253B%2520i%252B%252B%29%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this%255BpropsToCopy%255Bi%255D%255D%2520%253D%2520error%255BpropsToCopy%255Bi%255D%255D%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.name%2520%253D%2520name%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520constructor.apply%28this%252C%2520Array.prototype.slice.call%28arguments%252C%25201%29%29%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520func.prototype%2520%253D%2520Object.create%28parent.prototype%29%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520func.prototype.constructor%2520%253D%2520func%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520func.name%2520%253D%2520constructor.name%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520return%2520func%253B%250A%257D%250A%250A%252F**%250A%2520*%2520%2540constructor%250A%2520*%2520%2540extends%2520%257BError%257D%250A%2520*%2520%2540param%2520%257BError%257D%2520err%250A%2520*%2520%2540param%2520%257Bnumber%257D%2520bar%250A%2520*%2520%2540param%2520%257Bnumber%257D%2520baz%250A%2520**%252F%250Avar%2520FooError%2520%253D%2520function%28err%252C%2520bar%252C%2520baz%29%2520%257B%257D%253B%250A%250AFooError%2520%253D%2520subclassError%28'FooError'%252C%2520null%252C%2520function%2520%28bar%252C%2520baz%29%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520this.message%2520%253D%2520%2522invalid%2520bar%253A%2520'%2522%2520%252B%2520bar%2520%252B%2520%2522'%252C%2520%28using%2520'%2522%2520%252B%2520baz%2520%252B%2520%2522'%29%2522%253B%250A%257D%29%253B%250A%250A%252F**%250A%2520*%2520Frobs%2520the%2520noid.%250A%2520*%2520%2540param%2520%257Bnumber%257D%2520x%250A%2520*%2520%2540param%2520%257Bnumber%257D%2520y%250A%2520*%2520%2540throws%2520FooError%250A**%252F%250Afunction%2520frob%2520%28x%252C%2520y%29%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520if%2520%28x%2520%253C%25200%29%2520throw%2520new%2520FooError%28new%2520Error%28%29%252C%2520x%252C%2520y%29%253B%250A%257D)

Comment: I wish I could avoid the doing the stub, but this is still an awesome answer. I'd +10 if I could. Thanks for being so knowledgeable, Chad!

Comment: And on second thought, for the amount of type-checking complexity involved here, writing a stub is about as simple as I could hope for. Works well.

Comment: That's why I wrote the answer this way. I assumed your constructors would be highly variable.